# How to hide datavalues of a pivot for a particular rowitem value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a request to show pivot as below.

```
x11111
  y111111    8/10/2018    5/20/2018
    z11111
x22222
  y222222    5/20/2018    7/10/2018
    z22222
```

The dataset behind this havs values for all datavalues, so I need to hide the datavalues that are corresponding to `x11111`,`z11111`, `x22222`, `z22222` and so on.
I researched but unable to find an optimal solution.

Comment: I've improved the post formatting: please remember to write your questions with a easily readable formatting :) Take a look at [the editing help] for more information

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by changing the fonts to white so I get the above format, if anyone have better answer let me know